# gnome-screenshot -a's annoying delay

Tags: gnome, gnome3, screenshot

I set a shortcut for taking a screenshot of an area (`gnome-screenshot -a`) but whenever I press it it's an annoying game of cat and mouse to get the cross-hatch which lets you select the area to show up. When I just press the shortcut once the cross-hatch doesn't show up so I have to hold it down and watch the cursor flick between an arrow and the cross intermittently. When I stop holding it down it's no guarantee I "land" on the cross-hatch.
It's a pain in the ass. How do I get it to respond correctly?
This is a bit hard to explain, sorry.

Using GNOME 3 on Debian Jessie.

I set the shortcut made with GNOME (system settings, keyboard, shortcuts, custom shortcuts)

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/528777/304444

Answer (score 1):

As [meuh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/119298/meuh) said in the (answering) comment: You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> as mentioned in [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190741/119298). It's confirmed to work under gnome3, debian jessie, by [the OP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/163973/nebulon).

If you had MATE instead, [the OP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/163973/nebulon) commented, that you would use <kbd>function</kbd>+<kbd>printscreen</kbd> instead.