# Run gnome-screenshot -a with Cinnamon keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon, screenshot

I used the 'keyboard' section in Cinnamon's Python System Settings application to create a custom shortcut that executes the command `gnome-screenshot -a` every time I press the Print Screen key. It does not work as expected. Instead of displaying the cross used to select the portion of the screen to take a screen shot of, the system makes a 'beeping' sound. gnome-screenshot gets executed, and outputs the following to stderr:

```
** Message: Unable to use GNOME Shell's builtin screenshot interface, resorting to fallback X11.

(gnome-screenshot:6577): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_from_surface: assertion 'width > 0 && height > 0' failed

(gnome-screenshot:6577): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_window_resize: assertion 'width > 0' failed

** (gnome-screenshot:6577): CRITICAL **: Unable to capture a screenshot of any window
```

Running it from a terminal emulator (virtual console would work if you set the $DISPLAY environment variable and others) works and gives expected results. Occasionally, after pressing the Print Screen key a good ~50 times it will work as expected. Changing the command ran when pressing the Print Screen key to `gnome-screenshot -w` works perfectly, but I need to be able to select a portion of the screen to take a screen shot of. This question has been asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273870/gnome-screenshot-as-annoying-delay) but has no answer (the OP settled with using `gnome-screenshot -w` after it being pointed out in the comments that it works). My situation is exactly the same of the OP of the linked post.

So what can I do so I don't have to excessively press the Print Screen key just to take a screen shot?

Comment: Same trouble ( work only fast triple press hotkey. you can install xfce4-screenshooter - "xfce4-screenshooter -rs ~/Pictures/" , but it can't store full screen without asking file name , like gnome - "gnome-screenshot -f ~/Pictures/fname.png" ( i use both .

Comment: Did you make it work?
I find that if I create a launcher to run the script works well, if I run it from the terminal works well, displaying a warning. But if I bind it to a keyboard shortcut doesn't work.

Comment: https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/3981 has discussion of this issue. Instead of `gnome-screenshot`, I'm using `sh -c 'maim --select --highlight --color 1,.8,.1,.1 | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png'`

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation, where I bind the system's screenshot shortcuts to my scripts, so when I invoke the shortcut `gnome-screenshot` will take the screenshot, save it to a file and then open it with Gimp.

```
#!/bin/bash    
SSFile=~/Images/screenshot_window.png
# This command takes a window screenshot and saves it to a file
gnome-screenshot -w -f $SSFile
flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP $SSFile
```

In order to grab an area, just replace `-w` with `-a` and prepend `sleep 0.1` got it from [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=237055), so in my case the final script is:

```
#!/bin/bash    
SSFile=~/Images//screenshot_area.png
sleep 0.1
# Take a Screenshot from an area and saves it to a file
gnome-screenshot -a -f $SSFile
flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP $SSFile
```

Without the `sleep 0.1` part works fine when run from the terminal, nemo or a custom launcher, but not with the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score -1):

The command is correct.

```
gnome-screenshot -a -c
```

Avoid using the windows or super key, use association of free keys in the system.

Comment: Still doesn't work, and when it does, it just copies the screenshot to the clipboard instead of writing it to a file, which is what I need.